# Writing Xunit test cases in C#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, xunit.net

I am kind of learning to write unit test cases and I am using Xunit framework. I have a scenario where I would like to write a test case to test different scenario in my cosmos db emulator. To do that I am trying to create a database, container and insert few test data in my cosmos db emulator and then write my facts and also delete it once test cases are completed...below is the code which I figured out from internet, would like to know if I am doing it correctly... and where can I start writing my test cases.

```
    namespace Project.Tests
{
    public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly string CosmosEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
        private static readonly string EmulatorKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
        private static readonly string DatabaseId = "Recordings";
        private static readonly string RecordingCollection = "testdata";

    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

            } );
        var databaseCreationResult = client.CreateDatabaseAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId } ).Result;
        var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } ).Result;
        var recData = new Recordings { Id = "Test" };

        
        var itemResult = client
            .CreateDocumentAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( DatabaseId, RecordingCollection ), recData )
            .Result;            
        var document = client
            .ReadDocumentAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri( DatabaseId, RecordingCollection, itemResult.Resource.Id ) )
            .Result;            
        Recordings site = (dynamic)document.Resource;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Recordings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatabaseTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture fixture;

    public MyDatabaseTests( DatabaseFixture fixture )
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    // ... write tests, using fixture.Db to get access to the database server ...
}
```

}

Comment: That's not exactly a _unit_ test, though. _What_ do you want to test here? Whether cosmos db emulator works?

Comment: If you just want to start learning how to write tests, start with the _simplest_ task, you can come up with. Database End-To-End / Integration Testing is surely not it. Start with a simple function without dependencies or side-effects.

Comment: i am trying to insert data in my cosmos db emulator and have different test scenario which i would like to test with the inserted data.

Comment: so in one line i wanted to write unit test case where I initialize and create my db in emulator and insert data and then start writing my facts and then once done I can delete this db.

Comment: but suppose my db and container is already in there created in Cosmos emulator, can you tell me where I can start by calling the db and conatiner and inserting data and start writing my facts

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that using a web API is not really part of the Unit Test philosophy. A Unit Test is usually expected to be independent from external interaction.

You can still use xUnit to peform your testing, but you are not in a UNIT test context.
If you have access to the code behind the service, you could Unit Test it without the Web layer. (as an exemple, you can Unit test directly the REST controller class.)

If you ignore this point, I think the response is already in your question.

You can directly write your tests in the test class.

```
public class MyDatabaseTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture fixture;

    public MyDatabaseTests( DatabaseFixture fixture )
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    // Write test method here
    [Fact]
    private void MyTestMethod()
    {
        // Prepare Test
        /// Prepare your test data here.

        // Execute Test
        /// Execute your test operation here.

        // Validate Test
        ///  Use Assert methods here.
        /// Assert.True(....);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so I should start from inserting data in the db and writing my test case. Initial idea was to initialize and control my db(i.e. start cosmos db emulator, create db and container) with powershell api from my devops pipeline and then run the unit test cases. I think this is what you are trying to say. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It would technically works. But I would not suggest testing a database this way in your CICD.

Comment: can you help me in above code where should i write code to call my database and insert data, and how can i delete data once the testing is completed